# How to remove the gap between products in woocommerce archives page?

Tags: css, woocommerce

How do i remove the white gaps between the products and also how do i overlay the product title with the product image?

Comment: Send me your screenshot. I will help.

Comment: just click on the question

Comment: Do you have live site. Can you please send

Comment: cdlpsandbox.com/shop

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry dude im new to these stuff! and the page is cdlpsandbox.com/shop

Comment: There is only one product , can you please add more products

Comment: one product? there are 15 products...

Comment: Have a look at the site now? @Vetri

Comment: Please see  my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .woo-entry-inner{position:relative;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product li.title{
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product li.title:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product li.title a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0pc;
    left: 0pc;
    bottom: 0pc;
    margin: auto;
    height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that saved my day! Thank you dude!

Comment: Also there is no content in the filter button. Have any idea?

Comment: You have to add some filters using wordpress widget

Answer (score 0):

Please use this CSS lines on your theme to get the output like following screenshot.

```
.woocommerce .products .product {
    padding: 0px;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .woo-entry-inner li.image-wrap .woo-entry-image img{
    width:100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: wow thank you dude! and also do u have any idea how to over lay the product title with the image?

Comment: I just did!!!!!